# flash player working in firefox and not in chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash

I have ubuntu 14.04 and latest firefox and chrome versions, videos are working on firefox normally but on chrome is not working, I tried both

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

and it didn't make any difference

Comment: Have you checked `chrome://plugins/` in your browser?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha yes flash player is there and enabled

Comment: Chrome includes its own Flash player which is completely independent of the two packages mentioned in your question. You should report this as a bug too Goole.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo application/x-shockwave-flash
swf swfl > ~/.mime.types
```

You may need to log out and back in.

Comment: why do i need to echo and command 'swf' is not found